# SQL update query with select subquery across different tables fills only first value from the first row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have got three different tables: person, person_pet and pet

```
create table person ( 
    id integer primary key,
    name text
);

create table person_pet (
    person_id integer,
    pet_id integer primary key
);

create table pet (
   id integer primary key,
   breed text,
   owner integer
);
```

After that, I inserted some values:

```
insert into person (id, name)
    values (0, "Name1"), (1, "Name2"), (2, "Name3");

insert into person_pet (person_id, pet_id)
    values (0,1), (1,0), (2,3), (1,2);

insert into pet (id, breed, owner)
    values (0, "PetA", null), (1, "PetB", null), (2, "PetC", null), (3, "PetD", null);
```

I want to update the data on the owner column in table pet to the actual id of the owner as displayed in the person_pet table. That is, I want the following result:

PET Table

```
id    breed    owner
0     PetA     1
1     PetB     0
2     PetC     1
3     PetD     2
```

I tried this SQL query with a select subquery:

```
update pet set owner = (
    select person.id
    from person, person_pet, pet
    where person.id = person_pet.person_id and
    person_pet.pet_id = pet.id
);
```

This produced this output (filling in the id of only one owner):

PET Table

```
id    breed    owner
0     PetA     1
1     PetB     1
2     PetC     1
3     PetD     1
```

If I run the subquery on its own,

```
select person.id 
    from person, person_pet, pet
    where person.id = person_pet.person_id and
    person_pet.pet_id = pet.id;
```

the result that I want comes up:

PET Table

```
id    breed    owner
0     PetA     1
1     PetB     0
2     PetC     1
3     PetD     2
```

But I don't manage to get this when using the update command.

Comment: Which `DBMS`? Because UPDATE with JOIN syntax varies for each DBMS.

Comment: @Arulkumar, It's SQLite3.

Comment: The only way known to me is to 'replace' the values in the 'pet' table while inserting new data by means of a 'select' query instead of using the 'values' syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I did this exercise as SQL SERVER solution,
might help you:

```
update pet set owner = person.id
from pet inner join person_pet on pet.id = person_pet.pet_id 
inner join person on person.id = person_pet.person_id
```

with this output:

```
id  breed   owner
0   PetA    1
1   PetB    0
2   PetC    1
3   PetD    2
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, 'update' in SQLite3 does not support a 'from' clause. I forgot to mention that it was sqlite3 - I ask excuses.

Answer (score 0):

For SQLite, please try the below format:

```
UPDATE pet 
SET owner = (
         SELECT PER.id
         FROM person PER
         INNER JOIN person_pet PPE ON PPE.person_id = PER.id
         INNER JOIN pet PET ON PET.id = PPE.pet_id)
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM pet);
```

Comment: the same result comes up. Only the id of one owner is filled in.

Comment: From what I gather,  when 'select' is part of an expression it returns only one value from the list - and this value might be randomly chosen by sqlite.